# Case sensitivity in matplotlib savefig

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, case-insensitive

while creating and saving plots of different parameter combinations in matplotlib I noticed a very weird behaviour regarding case sensitivity in the savefig function. The following example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.pdf")

x = np.linspace(0,20)
y = np.linspace(0,20)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("TEST.pdf")
```

will produce a single file named test.pdf which contains the range from 0 to 20. I assume this is because some overwrite check is not case sensitive and changes the export name.

Do you know if this is intended (propably not) or maybe a mac related issue (OSX 10.11 with homebrew python)?

Thanks,
nandurius

Answer (score 1):

File directories are never case sensitive so when it goes to save the TEST.pdf it will overwrite the original test.pdf. This is the same on mac as well as windows